# driven.js:30491 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import which refers to the line in react js application?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In my react js application,after webpack compilation it shows an error in console uncaught syntax error:Unexpected token import which refers to the line in **bundle.js** (output file) `import React from 'react';` .

this is the referred line and its adjacent lines.

```
    var replaceLocation = exports.replaceLocation = function replaceLocation(location, pathCoder, queryKey) {
      return updateLocation(location, pathCoder, queryKey, function (path) {
        if (getHashPath() !== path) replaceHashPath(path);
      });
    };
    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, __webpack_require__(3)))

/***/ }),
/* 282 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

    import React from 'react';
    import WatchableStore from 'watchable-store';
    import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

    import './animate.css';
    import './styles.css';
```

i dont know whats happening,am new in react... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error points to `import` keyword. ES6 modules don't work in browser environment, so you need to use [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) ([`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) for webpack) to compile ES6 unsupported code into ES5 code.

You need to set up `.babelrc` file with at least these presets:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

And then in webpack.config loaders:

```
{
  test: /.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader'
}
```

Here is one of the [articles](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setup-a-react-environment-using-webpack-and-babel) on this topic. You can find more yourself.